# How to update the first and the last specific word in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column named **description** with the following values:

```
'Row first AP form here AR form to all AP was'
'Row second AP form there AR form to all AP was'
'..........................................'
```

I try to replace the word **AP** with **WP** but only the first and the last one in the sentence like this:

```
'Row first WP form here AR form to all WP was'
'Row second WP form there AR form to all WP was'
'..........................................'
```

Could you please help me to get the updated data above with a script like this please?:

```
UPDATE
    SET description = REPLACE(description, ????)
WHERE description = 'Row %% AP form %% AR form to all AP was'
```

Comment: Does that code really execute? (`DESC` is an Oracle reserved word and should need to be delimited, like `"DESC"`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words)

Comment: Your sample data could be improved, e.g. add `'Row third AP AP whatever AP AP some. AP Another AP or sentence AP, BAPA .'`.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for warning. In the production it is `description`. I've already updated my question. About the samples, I would keep it clean. Thank you

Comment: What if a column value contains two sentences? Your sample data does not include such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `regexp_replace` to formulate your final string and use `regexp_count` to find the records to update as follows:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET description = REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(description, 'AP', 'WP', 1, 1), 
                  'AP', 'WP', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(description, ' AP ') - 1)
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(description, ' AP ') > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to update your data

```
        WITH data
         AS (SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE),
         d1
         AS (SELECT stuff,
                    Instr(stuff, ' AP ', 1)  start1,
                    Instr(stuff, ' AP ', -1) end1
             FROM   data),
         d2
         AS (SELECT stuff,
                    Regexp_replace(stuff, '(^.{'
                                          ||start1
                                          ||'})(.{1})(.*)$', '\1W\3') first_done,
                    end1
             FROM   d1)
    SELECT stuff,
           Regexp_replace(first_done, '(^.{'
                                      ||end1
                                      ||'})(.{1})(.*)$', '\1W\3')
    FROM   d2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace()` twice:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(str, 'AP', 'WP', 1,
                                     regexp_count(str, 'AP') - 1
                                    ),
                      'AP', 'WP', 1, 1
                     )
from (select 'Row first AP form here AR form to all AP was' as str from dual union all
      select 'Row second AP form there AR form to all AP was' as str from dual
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=98436698540ce3e0b252547a531a8c5e) is a db<>fiddle.